# severe errors in android studio due to something going wrong inside build.gradle

Tags: java, android

in android studio im getting a lot of errors because i think something must have happened in the build.gradle. I may have accidentally deleted the dependices method (or whatever it is) inside the build.gradle now everytime i try to run a gradle project sync this happens (below)
[image]

I have tried the invalidate caches/restart but that has not worked.
Here is my what my gradle settings look like. (below).

[image]

All my other projects in android studio seem to be working fine. Can someone please help me here.

Answer (score 0):

You misplaced the defaultConfig block. Should be like:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        applicationId "com.example.app"
    }
    buildTypes {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```